# how to configure cluster address in weblogic

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

I am configuring cluster which group of managed server in console. I have 2 managed server:

**Managed_server_name   listen_address  listen_port  ip_address**

> m1                       slc001.us.xxx.com    7001     10.1.1.1
>
> m2                       slc002.us.xxx.com    7002     10.1.1.2

So I created a cluster and added the two managed server to this cluster, the cluster message mode is unicast, now how do I configure cluster address? I have three options, which is correct one?

> 1. slc001.us.xxx.com:7001,slc002.us.xxx.com:7002
> 2. 10.1.1.1:7001,10.1.1.2:7002
> 3. 10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Both options 1 and 2 will work. Ideally I would use hostnames in case the IP ever changes. As an example of one of our clusters we use:

```
portal1:11602, portal2:11602
```

You must have the ssl port in there if you're using ssl, otherwise use the regular unsecure port.